# Como inserir uma Toolbar no ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android

Quero inserir um ícone como `Toolbar` mas o meu Android Studio denuncia um erro de conversão para [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)...
esse é o código do qual ele denuncia o erro:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open, DesR.string.drawer_close) { 
    ...
    ... 
};
```

ele dá erro na inserção do " `R.mipmap.ic_launcher`

Comment: como eu completo o meu método então?
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, drawerLayout, "O QUE INSERIR AQUI??", R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) { ... };

Answer (score 1):

Julgo que a razão é por estar a utilizar a *support.v7.app*.

Isto por si não é problema, a questão é que o construtor da classe *ActionBarDrawerToggle* da [support.v7](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle%28android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int%29) é diferente da [support.v4.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle%28android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

O construtor da classe  na *v7* não tem o parâmetro *drawerImageRes*

No seu código não inclua o parâmetro `R.mipmap.ic_launcher` ao chamar o construtor:

```
actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                        R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
```